# How do we define the Lie bracket on the complexification $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$?

Tags: lie-algebras

I already know how to do the complexification of a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ by the usual process of taking $\mathfrak{g}_\Bbb{C}$ to be $\mathfrak{g} \oplus i\mathfrak{g}$. Now suppose I take the approach of trying to complexify things using tensor products. I look at $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$ with the $\Bbb{R}$ - linear map

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f : &\mathfrak{g}& \longrightarrow \mathfrak{g} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C} \\
&v&\longmapsto v \otimes 1. \end{eqnarray*}$$

Now suppose I have an $\Bbb{R}$ - linear map map $h : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$ where $\mathfrak{h}$ is any other complex Lie algebra. Then I can define a $\Bbb{C}$ - linear map $g$ from the complexification $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$ to $\mathfrak{h}$ simply by defining the action on elementary tensors as

$$g(v \otimes i) = ih(v).$$

I have checked that $g$ is a $\Bbb{C}$ - linear map. Now my problem comes now in that my $f,g,h$ have to somehow be compatible with the bracket on $[\cdot,\cdot]_\mathfrak{g}$  of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]_\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{h}$. This is because I don't want them to just be linear maps but also Real/Complex Lie algebra homomorphisms.

> > **My question is:** How do we define the bracket on the complexification? A reasonable guess would be $[v \otimes i,w \otimes i] = \left([v,w] \otimes [i,i]\right)$ but this is zero.

**Edit:** Perhaps I should add, in the usual way of defining the complexification, the bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ extends ***uniquely*** to one on the complexification $\mathfrak{g} \oplus i\mathfrak{g}$. Should it not be the case now that my bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ extends ***uniquely*** to one on the tensor product then?

**Edit:** How do we know that the Lie Bracket defined by MTurgeon is well-defined? Does it follow from the fact that we are tensoring vector spaces, and so there is one and only one way to represent a vector in here?

Comment: Have you tried $[v\otimes \lambda,w\otimes \mu]=[v,w]\otimes \lambda\mu$?

Comment: @MTurgeon I think that should work. Guess I should not have asked this question so quickly.

Comment: @BenjaLim When we say "uniquely" we usually mean "uniquely satisfying some conditions". Do you have such conditions in mind? Extending implies that it should "restrict to the old bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$, but shouldn't there be a restriction about how it behaves on the $\mathbb{C}$-half of the tensor? My feeling could be completely wrong...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, it seems the right extension is the following:
$$[v\otimes\lambda,w\otimes\mu]:=[v,w]\otimes\lambda\mu.$$

This satisfies bilinearity, and Jacobi's identity. However, how can we show that this is the *unique* extension of the Lie bracket? We have the following result (taken, for example, from Bump's *Lie groups*):

**Proposition:** If $V$ and $U$ are real vector spaces, any $\mathbb R$-bilinear map $V\times V\to U$ extends uniquely to a $\mathbb C$-bilinear map $V_{\mathbb C}\times V_{\mathbb C}\to U_{\mathbb C}$.

**Proof:** This basically follows from the properties of tensor products. Any $\mathbb R$-bilinear map $V\times V\to U$ corresponds to a unique $\mathbb R$-linear map $V\otimes_{\mathbb R} V\to U$. But any $\mathbb R$-linear map extends uniquely to a $\mathbb C$-linear map of the complexified vector spaces (this is easy to prove). Hence, we have a $\mathbb C$-linear map $(V\otimes_{\mathbb R} V)_{\mathbb C}\to U_{\mathbb C}$. But we have the following isomorphism: 
$$(V\otimes_{\mathbb R} V)_{\mathbb C}\cong V_{\mathbb C}\otimes_{\mathbb C} V_{\mathbb C};$$
on the left-hand side, the tensor product is over $\mathbb R$, and on the right-hand side, it is over $\mathbb C$. Finally, our $\mathbb C$-linear map $V_{\mathbb C}\otimes_{\mathbb C} V_{\mathbb C}\to U_{\mathbb C}$ corresponds to a unique $\mathbb C$-bilinear map $V_{\mathbb C}\times V_{\mathbb C}\to U_{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in saying above you are doing $V \otimes_\Bbb{R} V$?

Comment: @BenjaLim Yes. I will add the subscript so it is no longer ambiguous.

Comment: I have edited my answer above concerning the isomorphism that you quoted.

Comment: Actually don't we have to check well-definiteness of the bracket that you defined above? Or is this immediate from the fact that we have bases to work with?

Answer (score 5):

Using the suggestion of MTurgeon we check that $g$ is a compatible with the Lie bracket on the complexification:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} g[v\otimes \lambda, w\otimes \mu] &=& g([v,w]_\mathfrak{g}\otimes \lambda\mu)\\
&=&\lambda\mu g([v,w]_\mathfrak{g} \otimes 1)\\
&=&\lambda \mu h([v,w]_\mathfrak{g}) \\
&=&\lambda\mu \big[h(v),h(w)\big]_\mathfrak{h}\\
&=& \big[ \lambda h(v),\mu h(w)\big]_\mathfrak{h}\\
&=&\bigg[g(v \otimes \lambda),g(w \otimes \mu)  \bigg]_\mathfrak{h}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

**Edit:** For those curious about MTurgeon's isomorphism below, recall this is coming from a more general result concerning isomorphisms involving extensions of scalars. The relevant isomorphism I will put here is Theorem 6.15 (2) in [here.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf)

> > Let $M$ be an $R$ - module and $N$ and $S$ - module with $f : R\to S$ a ring homomorphism. Then the $S$ - module $M \otimes_R N$ is isomorphic to $(S \otimes_R M)\otimes_S N$ by sending $1 \otimes m$ to $(1 \otimes m) \otimes n$.

MTurgeon's isomorphism now falls out applying $R= \Bbb{R}$, $S = \Bbb{C}$, $M = V$ and $ N = V \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$. Recall that $N$ is a $\Bbb{C}$ - module by extension of scalars with complex multiplication defined on elementary tensors as

$$\alpha( v \otimes \beta) = v \otimes (\alpha\beta)$$

for all $\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb{C}$ and $v \in V$.

Answer (score 3):

Another guess would be this?

$[v \otimes i,w \otimes i] = [v,w] \otimes i$

or  $[v \otimes i,w \otimes i] = [v,w] \otimes -1$?

I'm not quick enough to verify. In any case it seems you'd want to confine the defined bracket's working parts to the Lie algebra, and avoid involving the commutative ring.

Comment: I got three votes almost instantly but I have no idea which of my gueses is right :P

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I don't think your first suggestion satisfies bilinearity. As for myself, I voted for your second suggestion :)

Comment: @MTurgeon How do we know that the bracket extends uniquely to the tensor product? I guess that should have been my main question.

Comment: @BenjaLim I suggest you have a look at Chapter 11 in Daniel Bump's *Lie groups*

Comment: @MTurgeon I don't have a copy of that book, electronic or hardcopy right now. Can you post an answer about what it says concerning what I asked please? Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @BenjaLim Done.