# Are Lie algebra complexifications $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ equivalent to Lie algebra structures on $\mathfrak g\oplus \mathfrak g$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, lie-algebras

Given a real Lie algebra $\newcommand{\frakg}{\mathfrak{g}}\frakg$, its *complexification* $\frakg_{\mathbb C}$ is usually defined (*e.g.* [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_(Lie_theory))) as $\frakg_{\mathbb C}\equiv\frakg\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$. As far as I understand it, this means that the elements of $\frakg_{\mathbb C}$ have the form
$$\sum_i \alpha_i (t_i\otimes e_1) + \sum_i \beta_i (t_i\otimes e_2),$$
where $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in\mathbb R$, $t_i\in\frakg$, and $e_1,e_2$ are a basis for $\mathbb C\simeq\mathbb R^2$ (*e.g.* $e_1\simeq 1$ and $e_2\simeq i$).
In other words, the elements of $\frakg_{\mathbb C}$ are pairs $(g,g')$ with $g,g'\in\frakg$, that is, elements of $\frakg\oplus\frakg$.

The Lie algebra structure on this space would then be derived from that of $\frakg$ as:
$$[(g,g'),(h,h')] \equiv ([g,h]-[g',h'], [g,h'] + [g',h]), \qquad g,g',h,h'.$$
So can we write that $\frakg_{\mathbb C}\simeq \frakg\oplus\frak g$? What about the case of $\frakg$ being a Lie algebra on some more generic field $\mathbb F$? Does this still hold in that case?

Comment: One can write $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}} \simeq \mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}$ only if one makes clear that this is an isomorphism *of real vector spaces and* ***nothing else***. The RHS has no natural $\mathbb{C}$-vector space structure, and maybe more importantly, the Lie algebra structure on it which you exhibit is *not* the one of the direct sum *of Lie algebras*, which everyone would at first assume is meant when seeing $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks, that makes sense. So you are saying that there isn't any Lie algebra isomorphism $\phi:\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}\to\mathfrak g\oplus\mathfrak g$, despite there being an isomorphism between the underlying vector spaces, and both having a Lie algebra structure? But is there actually a Lie algebra isomorphism in at least some cases? I've seen stated e.g. that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)_{\mathbb C}\simeq \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/641125/173147)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg also, is the Lie algebra structure I defined the correct one at least? I thought so, but then I've also seen the Lie algebra structure on $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ defined as $[v\otimes\lambda,w\otimes\mu]:=[v,w]\otimes\lambda\mu$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188830/173147. Are these equivalent definitions?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, yes, they are equivalent, and that should be an easy exercise: Just write out $\lambda= \lambda_1+ i\cdot \lambda_2$ with real $\lambda_i$, likewise with $\mu$, put it in your formula and end up with $((\lambda_1\mu_1-\lambda_2\mu_2) [v,w], (\lambda_1\mu_2+\lambda_2\mu_1) [v,w])$ which is ...

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I'll try to write up an answer when I have time today or tomorrow. Upshot: In some trivial ($\mathfrak{g}$ abelian) or very special ($\mathfrak{g} =$ a simple complex Lie algebra but viewed as real Lie algebra via scalar restriction) cases, there are such isomorphisms respecting the Lie algebra structure. In many cases (any simple real Lie algebra which does not come via scalar restriction from a complex one) the LHS and RHS are definitely *not* isomorphic, and in many more cases (everything between semisimple and abelian) I honestly have no clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $E \vert K$ be a field extension; to play it safe, let's assume the characteristic is $0$, and all dimensions are finite. It is useful for what follows to introduce an explicit notation for **scalar restriction**: If $V$ is any vector space (or later $\mathfrak g$ a Lie algebra) over $E$, let's call $R_{E \vert K} V$ (or later $R_{E\vert K} \mathfrak g$) the same additive group (Lie algebra) but viewed as a vector apace (Lie algebra) over $K$.

On the other hand one has **scalar extension**: If $V$ is a vector space (or $\mathfrak g$ a Lie algebra) over $K$, then $V_E := E \otimes_K V$ (or $\mathfrak g_E := E \otimes_K \mathfrak g$) is a vector space (Lie algebra) over $E$. (The Lie bracket on $\mathfrak g_E$ is defined as the unique bilinear map satisfying $[e_1 \otimes g_1, e_2 \otimes g_2] = e_1e_2 \otimes [g_1, g_2]$.)

Note that in spite of what one might think when first hearing the names, *scalar restriction and scalar extension are **not at all inverse to each other***.

If we first look at vector spaces for a moment, everybody has learned in linear algebra that for an $E$-vector space $W$, we have that $R_{E\vert K} W$ is a $K$-vector space of dimension $[E:K] \cdot \mathrm{dim}_E(W)$, and for a $K$-vector space $V$, we have that $V_E$ is an $E$-vector space of dimension $\mathrm{dim}_E(V_E) = \mathrm{dim}_K(V)$. Consequently

$$R_{E\vert K}(V_E) \simeq V^{[E:K]} \qquad \text{ (iso of $K$-vector spaces)}$$

$$(R_{E\vert K}(W))_E \simeq W^{[E:K]} \qquad \text{ (iso of $E$-vector spaces)}$$

So now one might think that whilst not being the identity, the composition of scalar restriction with scalar extension would always come out as the $[E:K]$-fold direct sum in the respective categories. As the above shows this is the case for vector spaces. It is also true for *abelian* Lie algebras because they are basically the same as vector spaces. But as soon as we look at more intricate structures, it will in general not be the case. And, one runs into different problems depending on whether the scalars get "first restricted, then extended" or the other way around.

**Extension followed by restriction**:

You seem to think mostly about composition of restriction and extension this way around: Starting with a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ over the "small" field $K$ and relating its extension $\mathfrak g_E$ to some direct sum of it. Well here the first problem is that they are incomparable insofar as $\mathfrak g_E$ is an $E$-Lie algebra but $\mathfrak g$ (and any direct sum thereof) is a $K$-Lie algebra. So the only object that has a chance to be isomorphic to $\mathfrak g^{[E:K]}$ is not $\mathfrak g_E$ itself, but $R_{E\vert K} (\mathfrak g_E)$. However, in general it is not:

Example 1: Let $\mathfrak g$ be either $:= \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$ or the simple $\mathbb R$-Lie algebra $\mathfrak g := \mathfrak{su}_2$. Then in either case $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C} \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ and hence $R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})$ is a simple Lie algebra, also known as $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$, which is $\not \simeq \mathfrak g \oplus \mathfrak g$.

Example 1*: Actually, let $\mathfrak g$ be any absolutely simple Lie algebra over $K$ (that is, one such that any scalar extension of it stays simple; for example, all split simple Lie algebras are of that kind). Then by definition $\mathfrak g_E$ is simple, and [one can show that this makes $R_{E\vert K}(\mathfrak g_E)$ simple (as a $K$-Lie algebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3742748/96384) as well, so it cannot be isomorphic to $\mathfrak g^{[E:K]}$ as soon as $[E:K] \ge 2$.

Of course if one chooses a $K$-basis $e_1, ..., e_r$ for $E$, one can identify the underlying $K$-vector space of $\mathfrak g_E$ with an $r$-fold direct sum of $\mathfrak g$, however, this direct sum is not a direct sum of Lie algebras, as discussed in the comments. This means that in general $R_{E\vert K} ( \mathfrak g_E) \not \simeq \mathfrak g^{[E:K]}$ if the RHS is understood as a direct sum of Lie algebras.

**Restriction followed by extension:**

In more advanced algebra, one learns that this can go wrong for various reasons when, instead of vector spaces or Lie algebras, one looks at fields.

Example 2: Let $K:=\mathbb Q, E:=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. Then $$(R_{E\vert K}(E))_E = E\otimes_K E \simeq E \times L$$ where $L= E(\zeta_3) = E(\sqrt{-3})$ is the normal closure of $E$. Actually, that is an isomorphism of rings, which when viewed as isomorphism of $E$-algebras we should write
$$ (R_{E\vert K}(E))_E  \simeq E \times R_{L \vert E} (L).$$

In particular $(R_{E\vert K}(E))_E \not \simeq E \times E \times E$ as one would have naively hoped for in analogy with the vector space case. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_fields.

Now this dampens our hope for Lie algebras (and other kinds of algebras), as indeed:

Example 3: Let $E \vert K$ as in example 2, and let $\mathfrak g := \mathfrak{sl}_n(E)$. Then

$$(R_{E\vert K}(\mathfrak{g}))_E \simeq \mathfrak g \oplus R_{L\vert E}(\mathfrak{g}_L)$$

Now funnily, that second factor throws us back to composition the other way around, first extension and then restriction, but we saw in example 1* that (although $[L:E]=2$) that factor is not $\simeq \mathfrak g \oplus \mathfrak g$ but rather a simple (six-dimensional) $E$-Lie algebra. So we also have
$$(R_{E\vert K}(\mathfrak{g}))_E \not \simeq \mathfrak g^{[E:K]}.$$

**One good case for restriction followed by extension**: If $E\vert K$ is *Galois* and $\mathfrak g$ a split simple $E$-Lie algebra, $$(R_{E\vert K}\mathfrak g)_E \simeq \mathfrak g^{[E:K]}.$$

(Example 3 showed that the condition of $E\vert K$ being Galois is necessary. I am not sure if the condition that $\mathfrak g$ is *split* is necessary, i.e. without it it I neither have a proof nor a counterexample to the statement.)

In any case,  both conditions are automatically satisfied for $E\vert K = \mathbb C \vert \mathbb R$. That is:

If $\mathfrak g$ is a complex semisimple Lie algebra, then $(R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak g))_\mathbb C \simeq \mathfrak g \oplus \mathfrak g$.

---

Two final notes:

a) The examples above deal with *(semi)simple* Lie algebras and should give an idea what to expect and not to expect there. As noted earlier, the other extreme of *abelian* Lie algebras is trivially well-behaved like vector spaces. I have almost no idea what happens for Lie algebras between these extremes, i.e. solvable ones.

b) The answer in [Precise connection between complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639749/precise-connection-between-complexification-of-mathfraksu2-mathfrakso/641125#641125) which you link to in the comments would greatly benefit from using a notation for scalar restriction as above. Check for yourself that interpreted correctly, nothing in there contradicts anything in here, but one really needs to be careful to interpret it correctly. E.g. the first iso in there,

$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$$

with my notation should be written

$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3) \simeq R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R}(\mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C})$$

to make clear it's an iso of $\mathbb R$-Lie algebras, and actually came up in my example 1. And in point 2 of that answer, they're looking at an extension of a restriction of an extension, which would make any notation awkward, but if one in a first step abbreviated $\mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb C} \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2 (\mathbb C)$ it basically says the same as my last line in the "good case" applied to $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$.

---

**Added** in response to comments: Indeed I stress that if $V = \mathbb C^2$, then $Res_{\mathbb C\vert \mathbb R}V \simeq \mathbb R^4$.

While the nomenclature might be a little misleading at first, this is indeed the standard meaning of scalar restriction. But of course the thing you have in mind is also studied. What you want is:

> Given a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak G$, is there a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ such that $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C} \simeq \mathfrak G$?

Such a $\mathfrak g$ is called a **real form** of $\mathfrak G$, and finding such a real form would be an actual "inverse" of scalar extension (compare my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617936/96384), especially beginning of second paragraph, where I also note that we want this, but it's *not* what is called scalar restriction).

Now again, if we were just interested in vector spaces, this is trivial: If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $E$, then $K^n$ is a $K$-form of $V$, and it is the unique one up to iso of $K$-vector spaces. But again, as soon as we are interested in more intricate structures, we face dire problems:

**Problem A**: Not every complex Lie algebra has a real form.

See example 1.36 [here](https://faubox.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/dl/fiMYUbDntWM7oPPUUy3T55Fu/?inline).

**Widely celebrated result avoiding problem A for a large class of objects**: Every *semisimple* complex Lie algebra has a real form. Actually, it even has a form over $\mathbb Q$; or even over $\mathbb Z$. This is widely credited to Chevalley and more or less the content of volume 8 of Bourbaki's treatise on Lie Groups and Algebras.

Sounds good. But:

**Problem B**: Every non-zero complex semisimple Lie algebra has more than one real form. I.e. there are non-isomorphic real Lie algebras which have isomorphic complexifications. E.g. $\mathfrak{su}_2 \not \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$, but both have complexification $\simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$.

Actually, it is a celebrated result of E. Cartan's to classify all real semisimple Lie algebras, i.e. real forms of complex Lie algebras. I wrote my thesis partly about general approaches of this classification, partly about the exact classification over $p$-adic fields. Results over general characteristic $0$ fields are due largely to Tits in the 1960s and 1970s; I think that to this day some questions are open. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677910/96384, [Classification of real semisimple lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121110/96384) or this recent question just about possible forms of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$: [Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{C}$ has only these two real forms $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathfrak{su}_2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3859768/96384)

Comment: thanks, this is great. While I slowly parse all of it, a few questions: you mention that $E\otimes_K V$ is a VS over $E$. But why not a VS over $K$? Doesn't this notation mean that we are considering a space with basis $(e_i,v_j)$ with $e_i,v_j$ bases for $E$ and $V$ thought of as $K$-vector spaces? Although I guess one could define a $K$-linear isomorphism $f:(e,v)\mapsto ev$ mapping $E\otimes_K V$ into the $E$-vector space $V$ to identify the two things? I don't really know field theory that well (if at all) so I might be totally off-mark here.

Comment: also, when you say at the beginning that $R_{E|K}V$ is *the same additive group but viewed as a VS over $K$*, what do you mean exactly? Taking as an example a two-dimensional $V$ over $\mathbb C$, i.e. $\mathbb C^2$, is $R_{\mathbb C|\mathbb R}V=\mathbb R^2$ because instead of considering $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb C}(\{e_1,e_2\})$ we now consider $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb R}(\{e_1,e_2\})$? Or is it instead $\mathbb C^2$ thought of as a $\mathbb R$-vector space in double the number of dimensions, i.e. something like $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb R}(\{e_1,e_2,ie_1,ie_2\})$?

Comment: the latter interpretation would be more consistent with for example the result you state about the dimension of such restriction as a $K$-vector space being equal to $[E:K]\mathrm{dim}(W)$. But at the same time, I always assumed the word "restriction" was to be understood in this context as actually *restricting* the underlying field. This interpretation doesn't sound like a "restriction" at all to me, but rather more like a *reinterpretation*. I guess it's only a restriction in the sense that we "forget" that some basis elements can be sent into each other via scalar multiplication

Comment: See addendum. Definitely "the latter" interpretation. I do not fully understand your first comment though. To begin with, $V$ is a $K$-vector space. If $\{v_i\}$ is a $K$-basis of $V$, then $\{1 \otimes v_i\}$ is an $E$-basis of $E \otimes_K V$. The scalar extension $E\otimes V$ is naturally an $E$-vector space via multiplication from the left with $E$-scalars. Of course then one can *also* view it as a $K$-vector space, but this "re-viewing" it is exactly scalar restriction.